# skipAnnotations ignored in Maven PMD plugin

Tags: maven, pmd

I'm specifying `skipAnnotations` with value `true` for the default PMD `strings.xml` ruleset:

```
<rule ref="rulesets/java/strings.xml">
    <properties>
        <property name="skipAnnotations" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</rule>
```

It is ignored in a simple case like

```
public class NewMain {

    @SuppressWarnings("PMD.UnusedFormalParameter")
    private void method1(Object arg1) {
        System.out.println("method1");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("PMD.UnusedFormalParameter")
    private void method2(Object arg1) {
        System.out.println("method2");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("PMD.UnusedFormalParameter")
    private void method3(Object arg1) {
        System.out.println("method3");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("PMD.UnusedFormalParameter")
    private void method4(Object arg1) {
        System.out.println("method4");
    }
}
```

i.e. `mvn validate` fails due to `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin:3.8:check (pmd-check) on project pmd-skip-annotations-demo: You have 1 PMD violation. [...]`.

A MCVE is at https://github.com/krichter722/pmd-skip-annotations-demo.

I'm using `maven-pmd-plugin` 3.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property corresponds to a given rule, not to the whole ruleset. Therefore, your configuration is invalid, you should write:

```
<rule ref="rulesets/java/strings.xml/AvoidDuplicateLiterals">
    <properties>
        <property name="skipAnnotations" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</rule>
```

To include the whole strings ruleset, but have this property, you should write

```
<rule ref="rulesets/java/strings.xml">
    <exclude name="AvoidDuplicateLiterals"/>
</rule>
<rule ref="rulesets/java/strings.xml/AvoidDuplicateLiterals">
    <properties>
        <property name="skipAnnotations" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</rule>
```

Comment: I see, thank you. How would I have figured this out from the documentation? I don't seem to find a Maven PMD plugin page explaining or linking the use of properties. I'd appreciate the info and eventually suggest an improvement to make it easier to find.

Comment: This isn't really a Maven issue at all. The Maven plugin just wraps around the PMD Ant task. The configuration of PMD is the same regardless of how you use it (IDE, Gradle, Maven, Ant, CLI...). Refer to the official docs on how to setup your ruleset: https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.8.1/customizing/howtomakearuleset.html